# behavior of python round functions when the inputs is of the type np.float64

Tags: python, numpy

I find quite weird that the function round of python returns a **numpy.float64** when the input is a **numpy.float64** but it returns a ***int*** when the 
input is a **float**. Example:

```
from numpy import float64
type(round(float64(3243.43)))
>>> numpy.float64
type(round(float(3243.43)))
>>> int
```

Why round is returning in the first line a numpy.float64 and not and int?

Note:
I am using: Python 3.5.1  [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: I have run the same example and returns me float in both cases

Comment: @efirvida: You're on Python 2, or a Python 3 version from before they changed the behavior.

Comment: I’m using python 2.7.9 and numpy 1.8

Comment: Python 2.7.11 compiled by GCC 4.8.4 on linux2, with Numpy 1.10.4. Getting `<type 'float'>` from both lines.

Comment: For me, both lines return a `float`, not a `numpy.float64`. (Python 2.7.10 [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)], numpy 1.9.3)

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.1 in  [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the argument is not a Python float, there is a behavior difference between Python 2 and 3.

In Python 2.x, `round()` will convert the argument to a `float`. In Python 3.x, `round()` calls the argument's `__round__` method. The `__round__` method can return a different type. Specifically, when the argument is an `int`, the result will be an `int`.

The same change was made to `math.ceil`, `math.floor`, and `math.trunc`. They call the corresponding `__ceil__`, `__floor__`, and `__trunc__` methods.

For more details, see [PEP 3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/)

Comment: I would add that to the answer that   `__round__` method for a int in python 3.x returns a integer.